# Formula to tell me best records based on values in 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that will give me the record that has the highest potential. The record that has the highest potential is based on the following conditions.

1. H column. The lower the number the better. (but not negative numbers)
2. I column. The higher the number the better.

The records that fulfill those two conditions the best are the most important records.

I tried: =(I+H) The lowest number from this formula would be the better records. Not sure if that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways you could do this, so pretty subjective. One way is to use the rank formula. We will use it twice to evaluate each column to assign a score and then we add these scores together to get what you refer to as potential. This will get you to the highest score (potential).

=IFERROR(RANK(IF(H2<0,0,H2),H:H,0),0)+RANK(I2,I:I,1)

The first rank formula will rank the lowest value above zero with the highest value. The lowest rank would be the highest number. It throws an error message with the values less than zero, hence iferror formula to set this as a value of zero (per your message above).

The second rank formula is more straightforward and ranks the highest value with the highest value.

These two are added together to arrive at the highest total score.

Below is an example screenshot. In this example there are two occurrences tied for highest potential.

[image]